# Android Custom Preview Window

Tags: xml, android

I am building an app and when i start launch it, it shows weird preview window wich is very diferent from the activity that i am lauching...I would like to know how to modify my theme style to have  a result like this:
[Google contacts app photo](http://cyrilmottier.com/media/2013/01/android-app-launching-made-gorgeaous/launching_contacts.png)

here is my style file with my custum theme:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <style name="Theme.InviteToIslam"      parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar.InviteToIslam</item>
     <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView</item>

    </style>

      <style name="MyActionBar.InviteToIslam" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_actionbar_pattern</item>
  </style>

      <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
      </style>
      <style name="DropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
      <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_invitetoislam</item>
      <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>



    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the instructions [here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/).

Looks like you already have a custom theme with an overriden `windowBackground` attribute, so you are halfway there.

However, I'm confused by the fact that you define two themes. Which one of them are you using for your activity in your app's manifest?

I guess it's `Theme.InviteToIslam`, which would explain why your windowBackground is not changed and thus why you see a wrong color while your activity is loading. So the solution is simple, just move the `windowBackground` attribute from `MyTheme`to `Theme.InviteToIslam`and delete `MyTheme`, I don't think you'll need it.

Comment: sorry the MyTheme was something that i dont use ...it was there just for test...and distraction made me post it here...but i'm using Theme.InviteToIslam Theme..