# Preview Screen Layout Android

Tags: android

When I restore an Activity from memory, I have a preview window for a couple of seconds.(Android OS just place it before loading all GUI stuff). I need to place a logo of an app in this preview window (I coded this as layout.xml) or make some splash screen (but not at the start of activity, but when it's restored).

To make situation more clear:

I have a layout with picture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shell1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like on this picture:

[image: layout]

But, I can't use this layout for preview window. And if i use only image for preview window, I have something like that:

[image: preview window]

P.s. The second picture is not from preview window, it's just used to show the situation.

What should I do to have a proper nice look of preview window? To have this image just in the middle of screen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want image to be in Center of Screen??

Comment: Yes, but in preview window, which defines as drawable, not layout.

Comment: are you adding images programatically?? or this is the layout??

Comment: Layout, not programmatically. I working with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664901/android-custom-preview-window  . And I need to have a preview window like on the first picture in my question.

Answer (score 2):

This is for first Screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/shell1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is for second Screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/shell1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using-

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/shell1" />
```

instead of -

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="194dp"
    android:layout_height="146dp"
    android:src="@drawable/shell1" />
```